# Перенаправление nginx на домем Google sites

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте.

```
Есть странички на google sites: 
https://sites.google.com/a/xxx/yyy/
https://sites.google.com/a/xxx/yyy/aaa
https://sites.google.com/a/xxx/yyy/bbb
https://sites.google.com/a/xxx/yyy/ccc/ddd
```

Есть сервак с Nginx - mysite.com

```
Хочу сделать так, чтобы при заходе на страницы 
mysite.com/google/  - открывался https://sites.google.com/a/xxx/yyy/
mysite.com/google/aaa  - открывался https://sites.google.com/a/xxx/yyy/aaa
mysite.com/google/bbb  - открывался https://sites.google.com/a/xxx/yyy/bbb
mysite.com/google/ccc/ddd  - открывался https://sites.google.com/a/xxx/yyy/ccc/ddd
```

не редиректил, т.е. как будто мы остаёмся в рамках текущего сайта. Как это возможно сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Прочитать что находится по требуему адресу редиректа и вывести на страницу, заменив предварительно все ссылки sites.google.com/a/xxx на
mysite.com/google/xxx

Comment: А почему бы не использовать iframe в таком случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /google/ {
        rewrite ^/google/(.*)$ /a/xxx/yyy/$1;
        proxy_pass https://sites.google.com;
        break;
    }

так :)
```

Answer (score 0):

как-то так:

location / {
    set $uri = "/xxx/yyy/" +$uri;
}

или через rewrite